# Getting 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices' error while running the code

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, google-api-client

I have added some code in my app in order to fetch current coordinates of the use, but I'm getting this error while trying to execute the code: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices` and `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.0_4c7bd3ba60681b6175bb19fbd50764675932470a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_b9f97537d3a2abc61db307c2c2ef7c174440060d-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_adf72fb3c70bac53e6797eaca25ced30ad36a335-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_9399547a058679bc5c3341a7d3e906a056face60-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_224aa852a21d8048ca714ef7a093680d664a0edc-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_125d777753353742bc7db69016f20f73d72a3540-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-de.hdodenhof-circleimageview-2.1.0_d40a213a7ffc82c49ad899031fb714d0756ec52e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.mikepenz-fastadapter-extensions-1.8.0_106c0a0873d7d109d11aafaa26743a3f4813a6a9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.mikepenz-fastadapter-1.8.2_dc84f0923ee8843a6eddc0162cda6ae33ab54ffa-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.4.0_5d9a65f9becfb5ddb8f9b990c25499017f057187-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-database-connection-9.4.0_06f485c91d5473b324ab248eecb3376ea33f2ca2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-database-9.4.0_da92bd8dfd1c5cf6b3723e9a98e97db4b6918b40-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.playrapp.playr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.googl`

Here's my code:

```
    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        String itemID, currentLatString, currentLngString;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mLastLocation;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        // error on the line below
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
            }

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        protected void onStart() {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            super.onStart();
        }

        protected void onStop() {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                currentLatString = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                currentLngString = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

    }
```

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.8.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:1.8.0@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

2nd gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**It is working perfectly in android emulator but not on my device running on Android L**

What is this error and why am I getting it???

Please let me know.

Comment: Make sure you have all the dependencies in the classpath

Comment: Check/show your gradle file

Comment: @MorrisonChang please see the edited question for Gradle file.

Comment: @PKR please checkout the edited question

Comment: Try enabling MultiDex support in your application. You can find detailed info @ https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html